# Migrate comments from LiveFyre?

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

We're looking at a comment system for a corporate brand website on product pages.  We've been leaning towards LiveFyre over Facebook Comments because of the potential to reach other social media markets such as Twitter.

However, we don't fully understand how it works and what the implication would be if we chose to migrate away from it at a later stage?  Where are the comments stored and if we switched to Disqus or Facebook Comments later, would the comments be kept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here was the official response from LiveFyre after I emailed them:

"My apologies, I must have missed that you were not on WordPress. At the moment, there is no storage of non-WordPress site's comments, but an API is in development to import and export those comments. While I don't have an exact ETA on that feature, definitely keep an eye on blog.livefyre.com for updates as we'll be posting them there first!"